# I flag as duplicate, OP edits, how do I "retract"?

Tags: support, review, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I recently flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612700/how-to-finding-differences-in-two-images-with-php) as a duplicate. It definitely was a spot on duplicate. In response the OP edited the question to change it's meaning almost entirely.

What is my correct cause of action then? To delete the comment that appeared when I marked it as duplicate? Or is there some more complex "retraction" mechanism I am missing?

Comment: You can always retract your flags? Also you could delete the generated comment in addition. What's the specific problem actually?

Comment: I just wondered if there was a "correct" or recommended response. If I delete the comment, the other comments won't flow.

Comment: _"... the other comments won't flow."_ flag them as _obsolete_ as usual then.

Comment: BTW, that question looks _too broad_ for my taste.

Comment: "flag them as obsolete as usual then." - There you are, that may be what I am looking for, I had not previously seen this functionality :) I flagged OP's comment as obsolete, and deleted my comments - all tidy. Feel free to add your comment as an answer....

Comment: If you no longer think it's a duplicate then yes, just retract the flag and delete the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is my correct cause of action then?

You can always retract any flags going back to the flagging dialog.

Since with a duplicate flag there came an automatically generated comment you should delete that comment also.

If there are other comments referring to that one, flag these as *obsolete*. Community moderators will be notified and tidy everything up.

Comment: Good answer. Note also that if the question has been closed, anyone with close vote privileges can also vote to reopen.